# Como faço para centralizar todo o conteúdo de uma tabela no LaTeX utilizando Overleaf?

Tags: latex

Todo o conteúdo da minha tabela está localizado à esquerda da mesma. Como faço para **centralizar o conteúdo das colunas e linhas desta tabela?**

- Foto da tabela.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Código da tabela.

```
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \footnotesize
     \caption{Tabela de cadastro de clientes}
        \begin{tabular}{|p{7cm}|p{7cm}|}
        \hline
        \rowcolor{lightgray}\textbf{RF01. Cadastrar cliente} & \textbf{RNF01.01} \\
        \hline
        O sistema deve permitir o cadastro de novos clientes. &  Só é permitido funcionários realizarem essa função. \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular} \\ [0.5cm]
    \textbf{Fonte:} Elaboração Própria (2020.1)
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Já tentou usar P{7cm} ou C{7cm} ?

Comment: @FourZeroFive vou verificar se isso dá certo.

Comment: @FourZeroFive funciona, mas ultrapassa um pouco a margem da página.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você quiser centralizar o conteúdo de todas as linhas e colunas me parece suficiente você colocar a tabela dentre as tags:

```
\begin{center}
(... sua tabela aqui ...)
\end{center}
```

https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/tables#Introduction

Já se você quiser centralizar a tabela em si:

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
 (... sua tabela aqui ...)
\end{table}
```

https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/tables#Positioning_tables

Comment: Eu tentei o primeiro trecho e funcionou, porém ocupa muito espaço na margem da lateral direita, o segundo ainda estou tentando fazer.

Comment: O segundo código executou, porém não surtiu efeito esperado ainda continua o mesmo.

Comment: acho que dá pra resolver tudo isso alterando a linha ```\begin{tabular}{|p{7cm}|p{7cm}|}``` agora estou tentando entender como faz.

Comment: ```\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}``` o problema é que a margem direita está muito para direita

Comment: Tenta dar uma olhada nessa página da documentação sobre tabelas que te passei que geralmente você consegue resolver a maioria dos problemas relacionados a tabela.

Comment: @Kyukay lembre-se que C maiusculo é diferente de c, e o mesmo vale pro P